# Else Condition prevents If Condition from executing in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I am trying to run the following code in Excel VBA but the **Else** condition mistakenly overrides the **If** condition. As a result, all every j record is identified as a *No match*. Yet, when I remove the **Else** condition, then the **If** condition runs properly and matches the j records to the appropriate i records.

```
For j = 1 To 27
For i = 1 To 37
    If Dec1998(i) = DecGIS(j) And Stream1998(i) = StreamGIS(j) And Trib1998(i) = TribGIS(j) Then
        ID_GIS(j) = Rec1998(i)
    Else 
        ID_GIS(j) = "No match"
    End If
Next i
Next j
```

For brevity, I have included only a sub-section of the entire code in the question. For clarity, I have attached screenshots of:

1. [j records (results with Else condition)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3Pc4.jpg)
2. [i records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRoRH.jpg)

Due to my lack of reputation points, I cannot upload any more images; otherwise I would provide the *j records without the Else condition* as well as a screenshot of the entire VBA code.

How can I modify my code so that the **Else** condition identifies the j records as "no match" ONLY when no corresponding i record exists?

Comment: You need to learn to use breakpoints (F9) and step through (F8) your code as it executes.

Comment: how is `DecGIS` and the others defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put it before the inner loop and exit inner loop after match is found.

This way `"No Match"` is the default and is overwritten if a match is found.

```
For j = 1 To 27
    ID_GIS(j) = "No match"
    For i = 1 To 37
        If Dec1998(i) = DecGIS(j) And Stream1998(i) = StreamGIS(j) And Trib1998(i) = TribGIS(j) Then
            ID_GIS(j) = Rec1998(i)
            Exit For                           
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```